# How to sort a map in C++ by value but if values are equal by keys?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort my map by ints, in decreasing order, but if values are equal, I want to sort by strings. I have this code where I sort a map and then write first k values to a vector:

```
   map<string, int> m;
vector<string> calc(int k) {
    typedef std::function<bool(std::pair<std::string, int>, std::pair<std::string, int>)> Comparator;

    Comparator compFunctor =
    [](std::pair<std::string, int> p1 ,std::pair<std::string, int> p2)
    {
        if(p1.second != p2.second){
            return p1.second > p2.second;
        }else{
            return p1.first > p2.first;
        }

    };
    std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>, Comparator> setOfWords(m.begin(), m.end(), compFunctor);
    int c = 0;
    vector<string> str;
    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++){
        if(c >= k){
            break;
        }
        str.push_back(it->first);
        c += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<str.size(); i++){
        cout << str[i] << " ";
    }

    return str;
}
};
```

However, it doesn't sort.

```
        auto cmp = [](std::pair<int,string> const & p1, std::pair<int,string> const & p2)
    {
                    if(p1.second != p2.second){
                        return p2.second > p1.second;
                  //  }
                 //   return true;
                    }else{
                        return p2.first > p1.first;
                    }
    };
    std::sort(m.begin(), m.end(), cmp);
```

I tried this as well but it doesn't even compile. It gives me Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::__map_iterator, int>, std::__1::__tree_node, int>, void *> *, long> >' and 'std::__1::__map_iterator, int>, std::__1::__tree_node, int>, void *> *, long> >')

Comment: You have a `std::map<string, int>`, but your `cmp` function compares `std::pair<int, string>`.  Did you mean `std::pair<string, int>`?

Comment: std::map is sorted container, what you mean by sorting of it?

Comment: jamesdlin oh sorry yeah it is vice versa

Comment: Öö Tiib so should I use unordered map instead?

Comment: I used this https://thispointer.com/how-to-sort-a-map-by-value-in-c/ as an example

Comment: You don't sort a map. It makes no sense. The order of elements in a map is fixed and cannot be changed. The order of elements in an unordered map is indeterminate but still cannot be changed.

Comment: @VictorySalta no, if you want to use std::sort then you should have sequence container like vector, list or deque. The set and map are always sorted by key and unordered_map and unordered_set are always sorted by hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working you only should loop over "setOfWords" instead of "m" when getting the sorted results.

```
    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++){
```

Comment: thanks for some reason I thought it sorts map :P silly me

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of comparing by *thing1* then *thing2* then ... is to use [`std::tuple`'s `operator <`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp), and [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to make a tuple by reference

```
using Item = std::pair<std::string, int>;
auto cmp = [](const Item & lhs, const Item & rhs) 
{ 
    return std::tie(lhs.second, lhs.first) < std::tie(rhs.second, rhs.first);
}
```